# how to remove fields in reassign task form sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, form

do you have any idea how i could remove the fields below without using InfoPath or any other tool aside from SharePoint Designer 2010? This is the form that shows up when a user wishes to reassign the task to another during an approval.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Open the workflow in SP designer. On the right hand side bottom, you will see a list of .xsn files which are infopath forms used by your workflow.

If there are more than one of these forms, you can identify the correct one with a bit of trial and error.

Once you have identified the correct one, just open it in Infopath, make the changes you need, save and publish!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nisarg. But I need to do it without the use of InfoPath. Is it possible to do it with SharePoint Designer only?

Comment: I doubt. We had similar restrictions, eventually we switched to 2013 workflows, and then designer will let you modify the form.

Comment: After researching a lot if there are any alternatives to do this, seems like the only way is to have InfoPath or switch to 2013 just like what @Nisarg  said.